# Why reference variable of type object must be cast when used as other object type

Tags: java, object, reference

Although all classes in Java are sub-classes of Object class, but different from other object types, a reference variable of type Object can't be assigned to any other reference type without a cast.

For example:

```
public class Inheritance {

    public static class Animal {        
        public void Scream() {
            System.out.println("I'm an animal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Mammal extends Animal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a mammal");
        }       
    }

    public  static class Tiger extends Mammal{
        public void Scream(){
            System.out.println("I'm a tiger");
        }       
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Animal tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.Scream(); //true

        Object tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.Scream(); //false

        Object tiger = new Tiger();
        ((Animal) tiger).Scream(); //true

    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't quite get your question. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you wanna know why we use explicit type cast.
this is all about Inheritance -

Let me clear this -
Let suppose we have two class **Class A** and **Class B**. And **Class B** is a sub class of **class A**. That means **Class B** has all functionality of **Class A**, this means **Class B** can do anything what **Class A** can do.
So if

```
 A a = new B();
```

is perfectly fine because **Class B** can do what **class A** can do.
Here reference varaible **a** is of type Class A, from a all the method of Class A will be invokable.Now Object of **B**(new B();) has all the functionality of **Class A** (as Inheritance) so all method of **Class A** will be invokable.

If we reverse the condition like this ->

```
      B b =new A();
```

Not possible, because may be **Class B** implement its own functionality(Methods and variables) which are not in **Class A**. But here reference variable is of type **B**, all the functionality of **Class B** will be invokable, But the actual object is of type **A** so Error will occur.

Same case is with **Class Object**.As all the other Class automatically inherit **Object** Class.

so When any object having reference variable of type Class Object need explicit Cast, Because this is not sure what more or less functionality that object contain.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've assigned `tiger` to an `Object` reference, the compiler no longer knows that it's actually a `Tiger`.  All it knows is that the `tiger` object is an `Object` -- it might be a `String`, `Integer`, `Fruitcake`, or `Animal`.

This is exactly how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Scream()` is not declared as a public method of `Object`, you can't call it on a variable of type `Object`. The compiler only knows the *static* type of variables (references), so it can't tell nor verify that this reference is going to point to an object of type `Tiger` at runtime (which would be its *dynamic* type). This is why you get a compilation error.

You may say it would be trivial for the compiler to verify the dynamic type in the case above, which is more or less correct. However, in real life, it is usually not so simple. Consider

```
Factory factory = new SomeFactory();
Object obj = factory.getProduct(param);
// What is obj's dynamic type?
```

The compiler could in theory detect that `factory`'s dynamic type is `SomeFactory`. Then all it should do is to statically analyse the code within `SomeFactory.getProduct()` to detect the type of the product returned. Of course, `getProduct` may return different types of actual products depending on its parameters. So the compiler would need to detect the possible value(s) of `param` at the point of invocation... Which may come from any number of sources, e.g. user input, config file, DB... But even if this was all surmountable, the concrete product class may be loaded dynamically by the class loader at runtime, from a jar file which may not even be available at compile time. So the compiler may not even be aware of the *existence* of this specific class, much less of its public interface.

Comment: @hqt, the compiler does not treat `(Animal)tiger` as a `Tiger`, but as an `Animal`. And since `Animal` declares a method called `Scream`, `((Animal) tiger).Scream()` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 2):

Given the statement:  `Object o = new Tiger();`

The type of the variable (Object) controls the interactions (methods) available to you while the type of the value (Tiger) controls the behavior that is executed for a given interaction.

By using an Object reference for a Tiger instance as in this example, you're saying that you want to use an instance of Tiger as an Object.  Well, an object doesn't have the method `Scream()` so it's not going to give you that option.  If you want to be able to `Scream()`, use it as a type that actually knows how to `Scream()` like `Animal` or `Mammal`

btw, methods should start with a lowercase