# The Object class is the parent class of all the classes in java by default

Tags: java

Why the reference type object o is not able to access variable a. It is showing error a can't be resolved or is not a field.

```
public class test2 {
int a;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object o = new test2();
    test2 t = new test2();
    t.a = 0;
    o.a = 10;


}
}
```

Comment: That code simply doesn't make sense. You're using fields and methods that don't even exist. What is `a`? What is `f()`?

Comment: object class has no field **a**, thats why

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Why reference variable of type object must be cast when use as other object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842378/why-reference-variable-of-type-object-must-be-cast-when-use-as-other-object-type), but it's still incomplete.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: and neither have a method `f()`

Comment: What does the title has to do with the question?

Comment: 1) Your question title is horrid 2) `Object` has no field `a`, thus the inability to access it 3) You have a wrong understanding of inheritance... `Object` does not have `test2`'s fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are confused between reference type and instance (object) type.

In your program, `o` is the reference variable with type `Object`, so `o` will be able to access only the methods and variables from `Object` class.
Also, `t` is the reference variable with type `test2`, so `t` can access class members of `test2`. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730109/difference-between-object-type-and-reference-type) for more details.

In short, reference type decides which members of the class you can access.

Also, look at the below popular classes for Inheritance to understand the above concept:

```
public class Animal {
   public String foodtype;
   //other members
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
   public String name;
   //other members
}

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new Dog();//'a' can access Anmial class members only
        a.foodtype = "meat"; //ok
        a.name = "puppy"; //compiler error

        Dog d = new Dog();//'d' can access both Animal and Dog class members
        d.foodtype = "meat"; //ok
        d.name = "puppy";//ok
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can't create fields just by assigning to them. You must declare them in your code also:

```
public class test2 {
    int a;
    ...
}
```

Even then, if you declare a variable as an Object, that is really a "test2" instance, you still won't be able to access field 'a' without casting it first.

```
Object o = new test2();
o.a = 5  // compile error
test2 t = (test2)o;
t.a = 5 // ok. Will compile fine
```

The Java compiler keeps things fairly simple, meaning that it doesn't work hard to see if "o" is really a test2 or not, it just uses the declared class to determine which fields and methods are accessible.